# What diference between ram-up in jmeter and ram-up in aws load test?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter

Im very confused.
Is there anyone help me clean that
im try to search google but i dont found
What if I configure ram-up parameter differently between jmter and aws?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They're the same because aws load test is using JMeter under the hood as the load generator.

According to [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

The idea is to increase the load **gradually** so you would be able to correlate increasing load with other metrics such as response time, throughput, number of errors, etc. as if you release all threads at once and test fails you will be able to state only that the system doesn't support that many users and it will be a form of a [spike test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing). You won't be able to tell how many users the system can support [providing maximum performance](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), acceptable performance, when it [starts degrading](https://www.educative.io/blog/performance-testing-101-bottlenecks), when the errors start occurring, etc.

It would be also a good idea to ramp-down the load gradually as well, in this case you will be able to check whether the system recovers when the load  gets back to normal or goes away.

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up Period: The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period)

Comment: What if I configure ram-up parameter differently between jmter and aws?

Comment: aws will override what you have in the test plan

Comment: include all number of thread parameters,
loop count,
Scheduler